# Proof on the number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

**Theorem.** A polynomial f of degree n over a field F has at most n roots in F.*

*Proof*. The results is obviously true for polynomials of degree **0** and degree **1**. We assume it to be true for polynomials of degree *n−1*. If *a* is a root of *f*, *f=(x−a)q* where *q* has degree *n−1*. Since *f(b)=0* if and only if *a=b* or *q(b)=0*, it follows by our inductive assumption that *f* has at most *n* roots.

I don't see why by our inductive assumption *f* has at most *n* roots. I know it has to be a simple reason, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are only looking at the maximum here. We have that $f(b) = 0\iff a=b \quad\text{or}\quad q(b)=0$. Now from the inductive assumption we have that $q(x)$ has *at most* $n-1$ roots. Then supposing that all those roots are distinct, and $a$ is also distinct from those, we can have at most $n-1$ roots for $q(x)$ plus an extra root $f(a)$ giving a maximum of $n$ roots.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that they are all distinct, but it does not matter. If $a$ is a root of $f(x)$, then you can factor $f(x) = (x-a)\cdot q(x)$. $q(x)$ is of degree $n-1$ so it has at most $n-1$ roots by the inductive hypothesis. $a$ may or may not be one of those roots. If it is, then $f(x)$ has at most $n-1$ roots (those of $q(x)$ which include $a$); if it isn't then it has at most $(n-1)+1 = n$ roots (those of $q(x)$ *plus* $a$). IOW, in both cases, it has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: @Nick I agree, edited my answer to remove that assumption.